# Random number generator with conditions - Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and trying to generate 5 numbers with 2 conditions:

1. There must be 3 even and 2 odd numbers
2. From those 5 numbers 3 must be low (1,51) and 2 high (51,100). Which number will be low or high is not of interest.

I have managed to solve the first part:

```
import random
rand_even = random.sample(range(0, 100, 2), 3)
rand_odd = random.sample(range(1, 100, 2), 2)
rand_total = rand_even,rand_odd
print(rand_total)
```

Obviously this is not getting me anywhere
For the second part i thought i could use something like:

```
rand_low = random.sample(range(0, 51), 3)
rand_high = random.sample(range(51,100), 2)
```

But obviously this is not the way as i am getting more than 5 numbers.

Any help would be appriciated.
Thank you

Comment: If you decide that 3 numbers will always be both even and low, and 2 numbers will always be odd and high, technically the question is solved. Perhaps you should randomly decide which fraction will be (even & low), or (even & high), then adjust your random samples

Comment: I could just stick with only the first code and run it till 5 numbers meet the criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, as pointed out by others, whether we allow correlations between the numbers being high/low and even/odd. The following code does not introduce this correlation.

```
import random
n = 5                                                                           
odd = 2                                                                         
high = 2                                                                        

odd_indices = random.sample(range(n), odd)                                      
high_indices = random.sample(range(n), high)                                    
out = random.sample(range(26),n)                                                
for i in range(n):                                                              
    out[i] *= 2                                                                 
    if i in odd_indices:                                                        
        out[i] += 1                                                             
    if i in high_indices:                                                       
        out[i] += 50
```

Please note that this includes the number 100 as output option. Strictly speaking you did not include it, so one could introduce a shift if the 100 is hit:

```
    if out[i]==100:
        out[i] -= random.sample(range(1,25),1)[0]*2
```

This code is not optimized for performance.

**edit**

This code will have an irregularity, though, as in each possible output `2k` and `2k+1` never occur at the same time for any `k`.

Comment: Works a treat! Thank you for your time and help

Answer (score 1):

I tried working through this problem *logically* and it got pretty messy.

Heuristically, what about something like this:

```py
def valid_list(l):
    evens, odds = 0, 0
    lows, highs = 0, 0
    for elem in l:
        if elem%2 == 0:
            evens += 1
        else:
            odds += 1
        if elem < 52:
            lows += 1
        else:
            highs += 1
    return evens <= 3 and odds <= 2 and lows <= 3 and highs <= 2

current_list = [random.randint(0, 100)]

while len(current_list) < 5:
    if not valid_list(current_list):
        current_list[-1] = random.randint(0, 100)
    else:
        current_list.append(random.randint(0, 100))

print(current_list)
```

You have a function that constantly checks whether the numbers you have so far are on track/valid, and then a while loop that will keep pegging said function with random numbers until there is a list of 5 numbers that pass `valid_list`.

This is pretty much the epitome of randomness, haha

Comment: Works great. Appreciate your time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care which numbers are high/low or even/odd, you can just say that the high numbers are even (since you need 3 low, and 3 even numbers).

This code just gives 3 low even numbers, and 2 high odd numbers:

```
import random
rand_even_low = random.sample(range(0, 52, 2), 3)
rand_odd_high = random.sample(range(51, 1000, 2), 2)
rand_total = rand_even_low + rand_odd_high
print(rand_total)
```

Comment: That would be great but then it wouldn't be random as i am biasing the code to choose lows and highs

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import seed
from random import random
import math
odd=0
even=0
below_50=0
above_50=0
numbers=[]
#Providing seed value to random()
seed(2)
while len(numbers)<5:
    num=math.floor(random()*100)
    #checking to maintain unique elements
    if num not in numbers:
        if num%2==0 and even<3:
            if num>50 and above_50<2:
                even+=1
                above_50+=1
                numbers.append(num)
            elif num<50 and below_50<3:
                even+=1
                below_50+=1
                numbers.append(num)
        elif num%2==1 and odd<2:
            if num>50 and above_50<2:
                odd+=1
                above_50+=1
                numbers.append(num)
            elif num<50 and below_50<3:
                odd+=1
                below_50+=1
                numbers.append(num)
```

Comment: Hi Mehul,
I tried your code in an online editor and i received " Runtime Exceeded"

Comment: For the parameters you provided, this code seems to run fine (python 3). Did you maybe increase the number of elements you sample to something close to 100? In that case, sampling numbers that are not in the list will take a long time.